# fullcalendar is slow when removing multiple events causing the browser to hang

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I used FullCalendar , created 1500 events.
Each event is related to a specific username.
I created a custom button that when user press on it - the calendar suppose to show him only the events related to him.
This mechanism actually works but I probably doing something wrong , because when there are few events (tested on ~10 events) this works fine , but now I have 1500 events and it hangs my browser and causing it to stuck..
any help will be appriciated.

code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: false, // Disable editing events directly from GUIhed over 2 days - this is the time that the run is counted as few days run
                customButtons: {
                    myReports: { //Filter my reports
                        text: 'My Reports',
                        click: function () {
                            events_to_remove = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                                <?php echo "var sessionUsername = \"".$username."\";\n";?>
                                return event.username != sessionUsername;
                            });
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource',events_to_remove);
                            $.each( events_to_remove, function( key, e ) {
                                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents',e.id);
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    allReports: { //Filter all reports
                        text: 'All Reports',
                        click: function() {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents');
                        }
                    }
                },

                header: {
                    left: 'myReports allReports',
                    center: 'prev title next',
                    right: 'today agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',

                },

                //read DB
                events: {
                    url: 'modules/scheduler/scheduler_backend.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        type: 'fetch',
                        start: $('calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start,
                        end: $('calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end,
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                    },

                    success: function(response){
                      //console.log(response); //For debug
                    }
                },

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. made the remove events more elegant  :

```
customButtons: {
                    myReports: { //Filter my reports
                        text: 'My Reports',
                        click: function () {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents',function(event) {
                                <?php echo "var sessionUsername = \"".$username."\";\n";?>
                                return event.username != sessionUsername;
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    allReports: { //Filter all reports
                        text: 'All Reports',
                        click: function() {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents');
                        }
                    }
                },
```